# Template specialization using another template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a problem with the template specialization, here's my example code:

```cpp
struct Base;

template< class CLASS = Base >
void saySomething( const CLASS &b ) {
    std::cout << "I'm base!\n";
}

struct Base {
};

template< class CLASS = Base >
struct X : public CLASS {
    virtual void print() {
        saySomething< CLASS >( *this );
    }
};

struct Text : public Base {};

template< size_t size >
struct Number : public Base {};

template<>
void saySomething< Text >( const Text &t ) {
    std::cout << "I'm text!\n";
}

template< size_t N >
void saySomething< Number< N > >( const Number< N > &n ) {
    std::cout << "I'm number<" << N << ">!\n";
}

int main() {
    X< Text > t;
    t.print();

    X< Number< 4 > > n;
    n.print();

    return 0;
}
```

but this code doesn't compile. Here is a reason:

> error C2768:  'saySomething': illegal use of explicit template arguments

and the compiler points the error specifically to this line:

```cpp
template< size_t N >
void saySomething< Number< N > >( const Number< N > &n ) {
    std::cout << "I'm Number<" << N << ">!\n";
}
```

I tried without specifying the type in brackets like this:

```cpp
template< size_t N >
void saySomething( const Number< N > &n ) {
    std::cout << "I'm Number<" << N << ">!\n";
}
```

but the final result is:

> I'm text!

> I'm base!

When I want a result like this:

> I'm text!

> I'm Number< 4 >!

Is there any way to solve this problem? Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: You are attempting a partial specialization of a function template, but there ain't no such thing. Only class templates can be partially specialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do partial specialization of function templates, bu that's not allowed.

In this particular case, you can get the effect you want by writing the following overloads, so that you have either a complete specialization for `Text` or an overload for `Number<N>`, like this:

```
template <class CLASS = Base, size_t = 0>
void saySomething( const CLASS &b ) {
    std::cout << "I'm base!\n";
}

template <>
void saySomething<Text>( const Text &t ) {
    std::cout << "I'm text!\n";
}

template <class CLASS = Base, size_t N>
void saySomething(const Number<N> &n ) {
    std::cout << "I'm number<" << N << ">!\n";
}
```

Now the correct functions will be called. Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z94uwb).